# PowerShell Subsystem max_worker_threads reverts back to default after applying cumulative update for SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016, powershell

We change the PowerShell subsystem max_worker threads to 10, but after we install the latest cumulative update, it reverts back to 2.  Is there a way to keep that from happening?

```sql
SELECT  s.subsystem_id, 
        s.subsystem, 
        m.[text] AS [description], 
        s.max_worker_threads
FROM msdb.dbo.syssubsystems s
INNER JOIN msdb.sys.messages m ON s.description_id = m.message_id 
AND m.language_id = 1033
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an agent job that runs on start up to set the number of threads. Set the schedule option to Start Automatically when SQL server agent starts.